# Notifications on Flutter from a Django Server

Tags: flutter, django-rest-framework, push-notification, stream

I am developing a Flutter Application with Django Backend.
Our app has a feature to send notifications to user, which will be sent from the server.

I understood we need to build a stream for this.
But do we need external services to build our stream like [getstream.io](https://getstream.io)?

Or we can build our own stream using Django?

Comment: any update, how did you implement it?

Comment: Amazon SNS, and Yes, you do need an external service